# How to create a one-line list-item of three sections with ellipsis wrap for middle part?

Tags: html, css

I have a question mainly concerning css-wrapping and would appreciate any input. I have found some quite similar entries on stack-overflow but they don't exactly fit what I want to achieve.

I want a three-sectioned list-item which:

1. never uses more than one line
2. has a left and right section of variable size that should always be fully visible if the viewport isn't smaller than the sum of their widths (if so, be it and I will accept some overflow)
3. the right section should float to the right, the left to the left, the middle left
4. has a middle part of which the content is supposed to be cut of with "..." in case the viewport is not sufficient to contain all information at once, so left and right are still fully shown while middle part is cut of more and more with shrinking viewport size.

This fiddle may explain the structure better and contains my vain attempt to achieve this behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/wdws1p64/18/

The relevant html-part:

```
<ul id="some-nice-list">
  <li>
     <div class="entry-left">
       <span class="not-wrapped info-left">
         Some exciting info:
       </span>
     </div>
     <div class="entry-mid">
       <span class="not-wrapped minimalistic-info">
         Some minimalistic information in that way that it should be ellipsed.
       </span>
     </div>
     <div class="not-wrapped entry-right">
       <span class="not-wrapped option-a">
         do A
       </span>
       <span class="not-wrapped option-b">
         do B
       </span>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Plus CSS:

```
li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.not-wrapped{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.entry-right{
  display: flex;
  margin-left:auto;
}

.minimalistic-info{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
```

As one can see, the right section gets pushed out of the viewport when shrinking. Setting a fixed width or max-width for the middle part would be quite unsatisfying.

If any further information is needed I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

...to the **parent** of the span to ellipsis

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.not-wrapped {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 .5em
}

.entry-right {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.entry-mid { /* changed to parent div */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="some-nice-list">
  <li>
    <div class="entry-left">
      <span class="not-wrapped info-left">
         Some exciting info:
       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="entry-mid">
      <span class="not-wrapped minimalistic-info">
         Some minimalistic information in that way that it should be ellipsed.
       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="not-wrapped entry-right">
      <span class="not-wrapped option-a">
         do A
       </span>
      <span class="not-wrapped option-b">
         do B
       </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```